# Does OS interact with CPU or memory

Tags: memory, operating-system, cpu

Does a computer's operating system interact with the CPU or directly with the Memory? Or both, depending on the computer?

Comment: Could you maybe get a bit more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the operating system is *in* memory, and is made up of instructions, which are executed by the CPU. So, both. Always.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have a computer without an OS, where the instructions are coded into the memory directly? Is this what is meant by direct memory access?

Comment: @Victor It is possible for the instructions to be hard-coded into ROM (read-only memory). But the instructions are still "in memory" in a sense. And no, direct memory access (DMA) refers to a peripheral device's ability to directly access system memory.

Answer (score -1):

"Or both," always...

Why would you expect otherwise?